# how to use IEEEeqnarray in standard latex classes?

Tags: ieeetran

Is it possible to use IEEEtran commands in standard latex classes, e.g. \documentclass{article}? I want to import IEEEtran as a package, not a documentclass.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the `IEEEtrantools` package.  See Appendix C of the `IEEEtran` documentation. There doesn't seem to be any independent documentation of the package in TeXLive except for a `.txt.` file that points to Mike Shell's webpage: [IEEEtranstools](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/tools/).

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was something like that; just got an error putting \usepackage{IEEEtr}. Anyhow; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the [IEEEtranstools](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/tools/) documentation page, get the content of the .txt file and then copy it in a file named after `<name_X>.sty` in your working directory. Whenever you want to invoke it, just use the `\usepackage{<name_X>}`. Sheer magic!